# Unable to read path parameters when POST body is added

Tags: java, rest, wildfly, resteasy

When I add a POST body, I can't read path parameters.

```
public class POJO {
    public int id;

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

...

```
@POST
@Path("/test/{a}/{b}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response test(@PathParam("a") String a, @PathParam("b") String b, POJO pojo){
     // a has the value of the POST body
     // b is empty
     // pojo is null
}
```

I POST to
/test/x/y

body:

```
{
    "id" : 1
}
```

header:

```
Content-Type : application/json
```

I looked at the example https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/ 
And can't figure out why I can't read the path parameters.
Here's a JBoss example:

```
@POST
@Path("book/{id}/comments")
public void addComment(@PathParam("id") String bookId, Comment comment);
```

Comment: the bookId and and comment vars are not valued when the methods is executed  ?

Comment: The code with book id and comment is an example from the resteasy link above. My code has the parameters a, b, and pojo

Comment: I see it. But is your path params are not valued(null) when the methods is executed  ?

Comment: When my method test gets executed, the variable "a" has the value of the POST body (which should go to pojo). Variables "b" and "pojo" are null.

Comment: You code seems fine . Can you show the imports ? The problem is maybe there.

Comment: It was the imports. I just realized I clicked the wrong PathParam import

Comment: I had imported javax.websocket.server.PathParam instead of javax.ws.rs.PathParam

Comment: Indeed, javax.websocket.server.PathParam will not be very helpful to do rest :)
Bye :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @davidhxxx my problem was the incorrect import for PathParam.

I had `import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;` instead of `import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;`